# Why does coliru return the same values for chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, coliru

While testing someone else's code on coliru, I noticed that `std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()` returns the same values on multiple runs. I tested the following code with g++ and clang++ on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a558e180e6658e6d).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << seed << "\n";
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
>
> 1433249917642594133
>
> 1433249917642674289

It does work as expected on [ideone](http://ideone.com/eiDtH5) and obviously on my computer.

Does anyone know why coliru returns the same values on every run?

Comment: if you edit the code slightly in each run e.g. add white-space then results vary in each run

Comment: @911 Ok, interesting. Weird. So the implementation has nothing to do with the `system_clock`. My question still stands. Or it's even broader. Is colirus version of `chrono` not reliable?

Comment: i thought old result is returned if no change to code.

Comment: @911 Got it. I opened a private window in Firefox, copy & pasted the code and got a different number. However, if you add whitespace on run number 2, and remove the same whitespace on run number 3, the result is the same as run number 1.

Comment: coliru is probably caching run results so if you rerun the same code it will serve up the last ran data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, no ;)

Comment: @Avi: Aww. Looked familiar from a recent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coliru caches the results of each snippet, so this is expected behaviour.

You can force a re-run by trivially altering the source file (by, say, adding more whitespace, or changing the contents of a comment).

<sub>*(**Source:** I know the author.)*</sub>

Comment: Ok, I can't argue with that source.